# SQL Server : search of multiple string values using a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search

I am trying to use `STRING_SPLIT()` on the parameter sent into a stored procedure to split up a comma-delimited list of strings, and I want to search by each one, only selecting unique records, from each search.

Rough idea of what I am trying:

```
PROCEDURE ListSearch 
    @stringList VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @t AS TABLE ([id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), [value] VARCHAR(100));

    INSERT INTO @t([value])
        SELECT [Value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@stringList, ',');

    DECLARE @i AS INT;

    SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM @t;

    DECLARE @j AS INT;
    SET @j = 1;

    WHILE (@j <= @i)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.Verses
        WHERE VerseContent LIKE '%' + CAST(@j AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'

        --AND KEEP SEARCHING, KEEPING UNIQUES

        SET @j += 1;
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Let's start with how your SP looks like, and from where did you get the unique row?

Comment: C# is sending in one parameter of comma-delimited list of strings, and I am trying to separate them, load them into a temp table, and search a table for all of the values

Comment: Why you need to load the data into a temp table since you already have a table since you are using `STRING_SPLIT()` function?

Comment: judging by that question, I suppose I don't

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56519132/edit) your question to include your SP there. Help us to help you.

Comment: edited with a rough idea of what I am trying. The parameter sent in would be something like "string 1, string 2, string 3" and my intention is to search the table for all three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a several wrong things there:

♦ You are passing the variable `@stringList` and just use it to fill the `@t` table variable.

♦ You are using a `WHILE` loop which will perform slow, and it's not needed there at all.

♦ You are selecting data from `dbo.Verses` but where the column `VerseContent` like the number stored in the `@j` variable, so you don't search in that table according to the values generated by the `SPLIT_STRING()` as you think.

♦ If you take a look at the syntax of creating a stored procedure, you will find that there is no need to `AS BEGIN`. See **[`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)** syntax.

Finally, from what you provide and what I understand, you are trying to do as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ListSearch 
(  
  @stringList varchar(500)
)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT V.*
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@StringList, ',') Str
  JOIN dbo.Verses V
  ON V.VerseContent LIKE CONCAT('%', Str.Value, '%');
```

Comment: the select and join are exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!